# convert list in specific string with conditions

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list

```
list = [ 'A', 'B', 'C']
```

I'd like to create a string as below:

```
' (( name = A) or (name = B) or (name = C)) '
```

Is there a lop i can use to add?

Comment: can you please add code that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
list = ["A", "B", "C"]

for char in list:
    st = " or ".join(f"(name = {char})" for char in list)

output = " (" + st + ") "
```

Output:

```
((name = A) or (name = B) or (name = C))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Try this

```
mylist=[ 'A', 'B', 'C']
mystring='name='
a=[mystring + s for s in mylist]
print(a)
```

output

```
['name=A', 'name=B', 'name=C']
```